# Private method parameters

Tags: c#

I have this method with an optional parameter.

```
public static Test(String connection, Int32 retryInfiniteLoopGuard = 0)
```

Is there a way to somehow mark the `retryInfiniteLoopGuard` as `private` so that it will become invisible when calling the method from outside of the class?

If you wonder why, `retryInfiniteLoopGuard` is for recursion execution and should not be visible to the users...

Today I use overloading, but is there any other way?

Comment: Out of sheer morbid curiosity - why do you want another way?

Comment: Because of the same reason that optional parameter was introduced in C# 4.0... I just want to take this a step further and hide the optional parameter

Comment: Optional parameter values in C# 4.0 are compiled by injecting those values at the callsite. I.e. even though your code is `Test(connection)`, the compiler actually generates a call like `Test(connection, 0)`. So, there is no way to achieve your desired behavior without using overloading.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a private overload of the method with that parameter and remove the parameter from the public verson. Than make the public version call the private version with the default value:

```
private static int Test(string connection, int retryInfiniteLoopGuard)
{
    // The code
}

public static int Test(String connection)
{
    return Test(connection, 0);
}
```

There is no other way to achieve that goal.

Comment: So did you really think that I don't know about overloading?

Comment: @user1662812: Indeed, it looked like this before you edited your question.

Comment: @user1662812 You'd be surprised what we have to assume or not assume about questions asked here. We have to - and *should* - keep a very open mind.

Answer (score 4):

### EDIT:  This feature appears to have never been added in.

In the new C# 6 you're able to do the following:

```
public static int Test(String connection, private Int32 retryInfintiteLoopGuard = 0)
{
    /* Enter Code Here */
}
```

Where it compiles as:

```
private static int test(String connection, Int32 retryInfiniteLoopGuard)
{
    /* Enter Code Here */
}
public static int Test(String connection)
{
   return test(connection, 0);
}
```

The way this works is all the parameters are implicitly as accessible as the method, unless of course explicitly stated otherwise.
The supported accessors are:

```
public
internal
protected
private
```

Comment: How do you make this work for you? I am targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1 (the latest right now) and using VS2017, yet this is not available to me.

Comment: I don't think this was released in C#6.

Comment: I actually came here hopping for something like this to exist in c#6. but it doesn't seem so.

Comment: @CME64 I don't remember answering this, but I was either confused or the feature I saw a feature being discussed but it was never actually implemented, strange.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why would you need it, but you can create two methods like this

```
public static Test(String connection, Int32 retryInfiniteLoopGuard)
{
    //method body
}

public static Test(String connection)
{
     Test(connection, 0);
}
```

Comment: Not quite what they wanted - the overload with the extra `int` should be private.

Comment: So did you really think that I don't know about overloading?

Comment: overloading clearly solves your problem. Whether you make the first method private or public is your decision. So, problem solved.

Comment: @george.zakaryan: If you make the first one public the problem is **not** solved.

Comment: btw, I bet there isn't another way